# Calculating TLE, or satellite orbit elements based on angle information (RA and Dec) at multiple epochs

Tags: orbit, orbital-elements

new here.
I am trying to 'determine' orbital elements of a given satellite.

Based on TLE from space-track, or CelesTrak, I observed several satellites resulting in 10 to 20 RA and Dec pairs for each satellite.

Therefore, I am wondering what is the most straightforward method/or package to produce orbital elements, or TLE based on those informations.

Yes, you can consider this project as checking if TLE based on 10 to 20 epochs within a day is close enough to original TLE.

Surely, I researched enough to realize I need to propagate through various force models, but all the answers, or hints I dug up are regarding TLE to (future) positions, not the other way around.

And I did not want to purchase ODTK, or even STK. Maybe MATLAB is ok.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I am a bit confused by your 2nd sentence: "Based on TLE from ... I observed ...". For each satellite, you have 10 to 20 pairs of angles (Right Ascension, Declination) that you call "observations" (per day). Are these "observations" independent from the satellite's Two-Line-Elements given by Space-Track or are they derived from them (using a propagator model)? (It seems to me that your 4th sentence is a clearer "statement of problem")

Comment: To carry out satellite tracking, you need something to have telescopes point at vicinities of satellites. Most cases, 'something' is TLE, and there are numerous mounts to 'track' satellites based on TLE. However, due to errors in TLE, satellites tend not to be in the center of FoV. Therefore, the observed angles (RA and Dec) are obtained independently, although satellite orbits determined based on these angle information should provide something similar. Hope it clarifies my question.

Comment: Yes, it is clearer. But, do I interpret correctly that you have the official procedure to construct a TLE based on a set of observations? (the other possibility is that you have your own procedure, but it may not be standard).

Comment: My first question is what the 'official' procedure to construct a TLE based on a set of observation is? To my short knowledge, the official TLEs are produced by NORAD, or JSpOC, right? So I try to construct 'unofficial' TLEs based on my observation data only. Or in some other satellite orbit formats. If your asked me if I understand the background physics and math to construct 'official' TLEs, yes, I do. But I want to know if there is a relatively simpleer package to construct a TLE based on observation data, rather than writing a code which converts data to feed them to a propagating script.

Comment: Yes, it's correct that the official procedure to derive the TLE is under control of NORAD. But it is not publicly disclosed (AFAIK). This means that even if you have exactly the same set of observations as NORAD, you would not end up in the same TLE as theirs. Your problem is then ill-defined. I think you can buy a program from AGI though. That solves your basic need, I think. Unless your objective is to have full control of the "physics and maths".

Comment: So back to my original question. AFAIK is not publicly disclosed, and I do not want to purchase ODTK from AGI. Then if I still want to construct, or determine orbital elements based on RA, Dec at multiple time epochs albeit with big uncertainties, where should I look at. PyEphem? Or some other packages I can play with? Is it even clearer? ^^

Comment: I am not familiar with PyEphem. I observe that (i) You don't have(want) access to the blackbox NORAD use to derive a TLE from a set of inputs, and (ii) when you are given a TLE, you don't know the set of inputs used. Yet, you are looking for an approximate routine (blackbox) that, from an approximate set of inputs, give you results "close enough" to the original TLE. And you hope (I suppose) that by "playing" with these (blackbox & input) you could somehow of reverse-engineer the official blackbox. I can't help as I feel something's ill-defined in the problem at hand. Nice project anyway.

Comment: OTOH, this publication by Vallado and Crawford [SGP4 Orbit Determination](https://celestrak.com/publications/AIAA/2008-6770/AIAA-2008-6770.pdf) may be of help if your want to code the "blackbox" yourself. Perhaps you have already read it?